# Why firstname and lastname fields are not entering in database but just the email and password in the customUser i created?

Tags: python, django, web-development-server, django-custom-user

I created a customUser from AbstractBaseUser with fields email, firstname, lastname and password which comes inbuilt and userManager from BaseUserManager as you can see below. But only the email and password are getting commited onto the database, not lastname and firstname. I use mysql as dbms.

model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
# Create your models here.  

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, firstname, lastname, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("user must have an email")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, email, firstname, lastname, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, firstname, lastname, password=password, is_staff=True)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, firstname, lastname, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, firstname, lastname, password=password, is_staff=True, is_admin=True)
        return user


class customUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=225, unique=True)
    firstname   = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    lastname    = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin       = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

I pass the values from my signup template

```
{% extends 'base1.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<form action="signup" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for=""> First Name : </label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Firstname"><br><br>
<label for="">Last Name : </label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Lastname"><br><br>
<label for=""> E-mail : </label>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email"><br><br>
<label for=""> Password : </label>
<input type="password" name="password1"><br><br>
<label for=""> Confirm Password : </label>
<input type="password" name="password2"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Signup" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>

<div>
{% for message in messages %}
<h3> {{message}} </h3>
{% endfor %}

</div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and use views.py to connect it to the model

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        firstname1 = request.POST['firstname']
        lastname1 = request.POST['lastname']
        email1 = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        if password1 == password2:
            if customUser.objects.filter(email=email1).exists():
                messages.info(request,'email already taken')
                return redirect('signup')
            else:
                user = customUser.objects.create_user(firstname=firstname1, lastname=lastname1, email=email1, password=password1)
                user.save()
                return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Password Doesnt Match')
            return redirect('signup')
    else:   
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

but the thing is in my database only the email, the password is getting stored, the firstname and lastname fields are empty whenever new user signup.
I'm providing my urls.py just in case

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'login'

urlpatterns = [
    path('ktupage/', views.ktupage, name='ktupage'),
    path('mgcourses/', views.mgcourses, name='mgcourses'),
    path('calicutcourses/', views.calicutcourses, name='calicutcourses'),
    path('mgcourses/mgaas/', views.mgaas, name='mgaas'),
    path('mgcourses/mgpara/', views.mgpara, name='mgpara'),
    path('calicutcourses/calicutaas/', views.calicutaas, name='calicutaas'),
    path('calicutcourses/calicutpara/', views.calicutpara, name='calicutpara'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
]
```

Comment: `AbstractBaseUser` already has `first_name` and `last_name`, don't make your own fields.

Comment: @AlexHall `AbstractUser` has `first_name` and `last_name` **not** `AbstractBaseUser`

Comment: no there is no first_name and last_name fields for customuser when you inherit from abstract base user.  I think the inbuit first_name and last_name is for abstract user and default user. you have to manually add those fields atleast I dont see a first_name and last_name in my database.

Comment: @safwan Check the answer.

Comment: Why are you using AbstractBaseUser? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @AlexHall I don't want to use the builtin authentication and don't want to use username as identifier but the email id.  I don't know if you can do that by inheriting abstract user. thank you for looking into it btw.

Comment: https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username

Comment: I think that's the article I have followed in my projects, but also just google "django user email as username"

Comment: @PedramParsian Thank you for your answer. If you dont mind can you please say whats wrong with the redirect in my views.py. I have a function signup which renders the signup template when method is GET. when the method is POST and if the email is already registered I want to send a message and redirect to the same page. But the browser says NoReverseMatch at /home/signup
Reverse for 'signup' not found. 'signup' is not a valid view function or pattern name.  you can see that in my urls.py I have a patternname called signup and a view called signup too. whats wrong here?

Comment: @safwan You have defined `app_name` in your urls, so the reverse should be `login:signup` **not** `signup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to set them in `create_user` method:

```
    def create_user(self, email, firstname, lastname, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("user must have an email")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.firstname = firstname  # <------
        user_obj.lastname = lastname    # <------
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj
```